# Async requests in Unity

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, unity-game-engine

I've been unable to make async requests in Unity 4.6 C#.
I have been trying out the WebAsync class from http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/WebAsync but don't know how to get the response data (I'm expecting a json string) from the result.

Answer on that would be appreciated, or another way to do this without the use of WebAsync would be ok too.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Do you really need this process in another thread ? If it's not critical, you can use Unity WWW class: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html It is still asynchronous if used in coroutine (with added bonus of being much simpler and you can use Unity API - not available in other threads).

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(AskServerSomething());
}

IEnumerator AskServerSomething() {
    WWW www = new WWW("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    yield return www;       
    if(www.error == null){
        print("success: " + www.text);
    } else {
        print("something wrong: " + www.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found WWW too, and was wondering if it really worked async - because I got it running right away. And yes, I definitely need to call this on another thread, otherwise it would block the UI I assume.

Comment: My example is async - coroutine guarantees it. It's just being run in the same thread. Multithreading in Unity is weak - you can not call any Unity methods from another thread.

Comment: As long as it doesn't block the UI it should be ok.

Comment: Coroutine isn't multithreading. I'm getting painful lag on Android when making API requests.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for downloading textures but it can pretty easily be changed up for json.

GL

```
private static async Task<Texture2D> DownloadTexture(string uri)
{
    // Debug.Log($"Download Texture {uri}");

    using (
        UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(uri, true)
    )
    {
        AsyncOperation asyncOp = uwr.SendWebRequest();

        // if (WeatherTracker.instance == null)
        // {
        //     uwr.Abort(); // todo: something related to this is crashing the editor while textures are still being download @jkr
        //     return Texture2D.redTexture;
        // }

        while (asyncOp.isDone == false)
        {
            if(!Application.isPlaying) return null;
            // Debug.Log($"{asyncOp.progress*100}% {uri}");
            await Task.Delay(1000 / 60);
        }

        // return this.uwr.SendWebRequest();
        // Debug.Log($"download tex {z}/{x}/{y}");
        if (uwr.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"{uwr.error}: {uri}");
            return Texture2D.redTexture;
        }
        else
        {
            // Debug.Log($"Texture Downloaded {uri}");
            var tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
            if(tex == null) tex = Texture2D.redTexture;
            return tex;
        }
    }
}
```